# Создание клиента SOAP запроса

Tags: python, soap

Создаю SOAP клиент, чтобы отправить запрос в PUESC (https://puesc.gov.pl/en/puesc).
На данный момент собрал полностью правильное тело запроса, но выдает ошибку "A security error was encountered when verifying the message". Скорее всего связано с правильностью написания тела запроса, т.к. пароль кодируется необычным способом.
Вот документация от SOAP:
http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf
https://puesc.gov.pl/documents/20123/603192553/PUESCKUD_SEAP_XML_PL.pdf/1553ee91-140b-56f3-d9e1-fc1bb1d39220?t=1623411653806

Вот сам код -

```
import requests
import hashlib
import base64
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date


endpoint = "https://wstest.puesc.gov.pl/seap_wsChannel/DocumentHandlingPort?wsdl"

login = "test"
password = "test"
nonce = "test"
today = date.today()
time = datetime.now()
time_2 = int(time.strftime("%H")) - 2
time_date = f'{today.year}-0{today.month}-{today.day}T{time_2}:{time.strftime("%M")}:{time.strftime("%S")}Z'
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(password.encode('utf-8'))
password_1 = hash_object.hexdigest()
message_bytes = password_1.encode('ascii')
password_2 = base64.b64encode(message_bytes).decode('utf-8')
password_3 = f'{nonce}{time_date}{password_2}'
hash_object = hashlib.sha1(password_3.encode('utf-8'))
password_4 = hash_object.hexdigest()
message_bytes = password_4.encode('ascii')
password_digiest = base64.b64encode(message_bytes).decode('utf-8')
print(password_3)



test = open('Test.xsd', 'rb') #open binary file in read mode
test_read = test.read()
test_64_encode = base64.encodebytes(test_read).decode('utf-8')
#print(test_64_encode)
body=f"""<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<soapenv:Envelope 
         xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/"
             xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
             xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing"
             xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd"
             xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd"
             xmlns:_v0="http://www.mf.gov.pl/uslugiBiznesowe/WsInfo/Usluga/2020/01_v0_3"
             xmlns:_v2="http://www.mf.gov.pl/uslugiBiznesowe/WsPull/Usluga/2014/01_v2_0"
             xmlns:_v21="http://www.mf.gov.pl/schematy/SISC/WsChannel/2014/01_v2_0">
             <soapenv:Header xmlns:wsa="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing">
             <wsa:Action>AcceptDocument</wsa:Action>
             <wsa:MessageID>urn:uuid:e1b9ba76-88e8-4989-a20c-bd658067703b</wsa:MessageID>
             <wsse:Security soapenv:mustunderstand="1">
                <wsse:UsernameToken>
                    <wsse:Username>{login}</wsse:Username>
                    <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">{password_digiest}</wsse:Password>
                    <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">{nonce}</wsse:Nonce>
                    <wsu:Created>{time_date}</wsu:Created>
                </wsse:UsernameToken>
            </wsse:Security></soapenv:Header>
            <soapenv:Body>
            <_v2:AcceptDocumentRequest>
            <document xmlns="http://www.mf.gov.pl/schematy/SISC/WsChannel/2014/01_v2_0">
        <content filename="taxfree.xml" mime="application/xml">{test_64_encode}</content>
        <targetSystems>
            <system>TAX FREE</system>
        </targetSystems>
        </document>
        </_v2:AcceptDocumentRequest>
        </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
"""

body = body.encode('utf-8')
session = requests.session()
session.headers = {"Content-Type": "text/xml; charset=utf-8"}
session.headers.update({"Content-Length": str(len(body))})
response = session.post(url=endpoint, data=body, verify=True)

print(response.content.decode('utf-8')[725:784])`
```

Может кто-то сталкивался с данной системой?
Или может подсказать почему выбивает данную ошибку, хотя запрос должен быть собран по всем правилам указанным в документации

Answer (score 0):

В `wsse:Nonce EncodingType` указан `Base64Binary`, а в коде он подставляется как есть. Возможно в этом проблема.

Comment: На будущее: вообще, такие предположения - это обычно комментарий,а не ответ.  Ответ - либо точно, либо развернуто хотя бы. Но при репутации менее 50 комментарии не дать, да.